# Javascript alert before a event call not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

```
strScriptString = "alert('Hello');";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Startup", strScriptString, true);

btn_Click(this, null);
```

**The alert is not showing up :(
please help**

Answer (score 0):

You need to still put the script tags around your alert:

```
strScriptString = "<script>alert('Hello');</script>";
```

**EDIT**

My mistake, read the wrong RegisterStartupScript class

Comment: No he doesn't because he passes `true` as last argument to the `RegisterStartupScript` method which automatically adds script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the source of the page for the script using Firebug?  I'll hazard a guess that if you remove `btn_Click(this, null);` it may work.

Comment: yeah..it will work that way but i need to have that btn_click.. when i had a custom js popup, it was showing up ..but this js alert is not coming

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code snippet into page_Load..

```
btnUpdate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GetAlert();");
```

Button Click event in code behind.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnUpdate.Text = "Reload";   
    }
```

Button in aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
```

Javascript for alert

```
<script>
        function GetAlert() {
            alert("123");
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: but, i just cant give the alert in attribute as based on some condition, this piece of code gets called !

Comment: actually, I was not clear...if i put the js in attribute, it will be called in all clicks of that button...but in that button click i have some conditions which when satisfies then alert and other event is called.

Comment: you should clear all the things here!!! you just right that alert is shown before button click event!!! that thing is work perfectly in my code!!!!!!

Comment: the button click has some functionalities like saving some data in db, if it is successful, then i get to show a pop up (success) and call other button event, else if there is a failure , we'll show a failure message..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4136/discussion-between-user258427-and-sikender)

Comment: you just need to do below things... 1). make a condition if you successfully make changes to the db then in that condition call fancybox jquery popup, and call 'onClosed': function() { UpdPanelUpdate() }, and put code like    function UpdPanelUpdate() {
        __doPostBack("buttonuniqueid", "");

    } 3). put button in page and make click event of that in code-behind. and put there your next logic or code.

Comment: If you don't get it, give me comment!!!!! I am not able to chat with you in chat room.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show an alert before the server-side event fires, use `OnClientClick`, and return true.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('Hi!');return true;" ... />
```